# Difficulties with routes translation and api

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am creating an API for my project and I have the following problem:

I'm using the location files.

```php
Route::group(array('prefix' => Config::get('app.locale_prefix')), function()
{
    Route::get('{contact}', 'WelcomeController@index'); 
});
```

This part of code works correctly, and I can access with

```
http://localhost/project/public/en
```

However, I am interested in create an API to receive a list of products. So I add this code:

```php
Route::group(array('prefix' => Config::get('app.locale_prefix')), function()
{
    Route::get('{contact}', 'WelcomeController@index'); 
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {

        Route::get('test', function(){
            return response()->json(['foo'=>'bar']);
        });

    });
});
```

I don't have any errors, but I can't receive a response. What is the problem?

```
http://localhost/project/public/en/api/test
```

**UPDATED**

I solve part os this problem , in the view I have this

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::asset((Config::get('app.locale_prefix',Request::segment(1))))}}"><?= trans('locale.allauctions'); ?></a></li>
```

This works correctly but I need to put en/anotherurl , how can I put this ?

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost/project/public/api/test` is working fine.

This is because your `Config::get('app.locale_prefix')` is empty! So you defined there is **NO** prefix. Use `dd(Config::get('app.locale_prefix'));` to test it.

**Why is `http://localhost/project/public/en` working then?**
Because you defined a variable `{contact}` in

```
Route::get('{contact}', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

and `en` is `{contact}` then.

Comment: Correct , I receive null in Config::get , now I have another problem XD

Comment: Set a default value: `Config::get('app.locale_prefix', 'en')` by default Laravel does: `Config::get('app.locale_prefix', null)`

Comment: I solve part os this problem , I have this , how can I put en/anotherurl ?